Wifi slow internet or ping latency and drops even within LAN on a Windows 10/11 laptop, unusual suspect
Just wanted to share a problem and a weird suspect (not thoroughly tested yet) i ve just found. A windows 10/11 machine connected wirelessly was bit lagging on YT videos and pings to router having spikes and drops every few seconds. Long story short, after some troubleshooting i found very unusual and ironic suspect/cause, a wifi scanner app called WifiInfoView. When app is running, wireless connection get laggy, pings are all over the place. I like Nirsoft and it's apps, not sure if it's the app or some compatibility issue with hardware.
Question is how could wifi scanner app cause latency and drops on wifi connection?
Note; machine has intel killer wifi adapter, 2.4g and 5g had same issue.

This isn't a question. Maybe it happens because it's putting a decent amount of load on your wireless card/computer, enough that it bogs down doing anything else that is also competing for the bandwidth?
